# Is there a Firefox extension to bookmark a specific position on a webpage?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Sometimes when I am reading a long webpage in Firefox, I want to bookmark a specific position within the page (not just the page itself).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

The Bookmark Anywhere userscript allows you to point the mouse anywhere on the page and to set a bookmark at that place. Recall the bookmark and the place will be remembered properly, including the scroll positions.

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/71694

Comment: It seems very old and hardly maintained. But can be worth giving it a try perhaps.

Comment: Note! requires Greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ Other than that, works well.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but there's an extension called Pagemark that looks promising:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Browser-Tweak/Pagemark.shtml

Comment: It looks a bit old though. :) Firefox v0.7 - v2.0.

Comment: Indeed, the way too ancient (no hope it could be functioning with 4.0 I believe). And not even in the Mozilla extensions directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bookmarklet from http://bquot.com that does exactly what are you asking.

Comment: The link seems dead.